# Pass a binding through a view preference in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass value changes of a binding into a view modifier. Similar to some of the other view modifiers that are being used inside Apple, e.g.;

```
func presentationDetents(
    _ detents: Set<PresentationDetent>,
    selection: Binding<PresentationDetent>
) -> some View
```

But the view modifier never gets called when the binding changes. Whenever I use a plain value it works.

Here is a single file example of what I'm trying to do and what works and what does not work marked.

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func changeNumber(number: Int) -> some View {
        print(number) // When running changeNumber with a plain value this does get called.
        return self
    }
    
    func changeNumber(number: Binding<Int>) -> some View {
        print("Binding", number) // Does not get called
        return self
    }
}

struct DebugView: View {
    @State var number = 0
    @State var selection: SwiftUI.PresentationDetent = .large
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change Number") {
                number = Int.random(in: 0..<50)
            }
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .changeNumber(number: $number) // $number breaks, number works.
        }
    }
}

struct DebugView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DebugView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `Binding` is only for SwiftUI `View`s it does not work in any other type of `struct` or `class` you are also telling swiftui to only reload a `View` when the `id` changes. Unless you have a really good reason dont alter the default implementation of `Equatable` and `Hashable`. SwiftUI depends on it to work.

Comment: Alright that might be the case. But do you know how SwiftUI then passes up the selection binding to the sheet? Or any other view modifier that accepts a binding? I would guess since the sheet is usually a parent, it should use this view preference pattern?

Comment: It’s just an argument, it has nothing to do with the environment or preferences.

Comment: Check, got it! Now that I played around with it, I see that. Thank you so far. I updated my question a little bit because there is one thing that I don't get. If I call the view modifier with a binding as an argument, the print function never gets called. When running it with a plain value, I see updates in the view modifier. How is that possible?

Comment: Aah if I request the wrappedValue it passes it on and keeps printing it. Think I got everything that I need then. Just need a different way of passing it up the view chain.

Comment: SwiftUI is very selective on how and when it redraws views it is getting more efficient with each version. It is never a good idea to do “work” as part of a view. There are designated “action” blocks for that.

Comment: Binding is a two way connection, State is a source of truth

Answer (score 0):

Alright, with some pointers of @lorem ipsum, I now know what I did wrong. I solved it by using the wrapped value on the preference key and passing that up in the view chain. Final code that does work;

```
import SwiftUI

public struct NumberKey: PreferenceKey {
    public static var defaultValue: Int = 0

    public static func reduce(value: inout Int, nextValue: () -> Int) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}


extension View {
    func changeNumber(number: Int) -> some View {
        print(number)
        return self
    }
    
    func changeNumber(number: Binding<Int>) -> some View {
        print("Binding", number.wrappedValue)
        return self.preference(key: NumberKey.self, value: number.wrappedValue)
    }
}

struct DebugView: View {
    @State var number = 0
    @State var selection: SwiftUI.PresentationDetent = .large
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change Number") {
                number = Int.random(in: 0..<50)
            }
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .changeNumber(number: $number)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(NumberKey.self) { value in
            print("Changed", value)
        }
    }
}

struct DebugView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DebugView()
    }
}
```